# difference between disk size in console vs disk utility

Tags: terminal, hard-drive

Console results `df -h`
[image: console]
disk utility results
[image: disk utility]

What explains the large difference here in capacity as well as used memory? And which is more reliable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be comparing Disk Utility with `df -H`. Mac OS X has been reporting disk space in base 10 since Snow Leopard.